# How to push to Observable of Array in Angular 4? RxJS

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I have a property on my service class as so:

```
articles: Observable<Article[]>;
```

It is populated by a getArticles() function using the standard `http.get().map()` solution.

**How can I manually push a new article in to this array; One that is not yet persisted and so not part of the http get?**

My scenario is, you create a new Article, and before it is saved I would like the Article[] array to have this new one pushed to it so it shows up in my list of articles.

Further more, This service is shared between 2 components, If component A consumes the service using ng `OnInit()` and binds the result to a repeating section `*ngFor`, **will updating the service array from component B simultaneously update the results in components A's `ngFor` section?** Or must I update the view manually?

Many Thanks,
Simon

Comment: Just to confirm, Simply put, how does one directly modify the array that this Observable contains?

Comment: Is this where I might use a Subject instead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you said in comments, I'd use a Subject.

The advantage of keeping `articles` observable rather than storing as an array is that http takes time, so you can subscribe and wait for results. Plus both components get any updates.

```js
// Mock http
const http = {
  get: (url) => Rx.Observable.of(['article1', 'article2']) 
}

const articles = new Rx.Subject();

const fetch = () => {
  return http.get('myUrl').map(x => x).do(data => articles.next(data))
}

const add = (article) => {
  articles.take(1).subscribe(current => {
    current.push(article);
    articles.next(current);
  })
}

// Subscribe to 
articles.subscribe(console.log)

// Action
fetch().subscribe(
  add('article3')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.2/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: Since `articles` is an observable, the components subscribe to it (in javascript) or use it directly on a template with the `async` filter. So since they connect via a reactive pipeline, they will update automatically whenever the Subject is updated.

Comment: Note, you can vary the **type** of Subject used depending on when components do the subscribing. A plain Subject is _probably_ fine for components that subscribe in ngOnInit or in the template, but if they subscribe late in the app flow (say ComponentB is on a secondary page), you may want to use a `ReplaySubject` which stores the last value and 'replays' it for new subscriptions.

Comment: I tend to think of `Subject` as the socket that components plug into, but it has no storage. `ReplaySubject` is a socket with (configurable) storage, and `BehaviorSubject` has storage for one item but can take an initial value - useful for providing some default value for components _before_ the fetch has filled in it's value.

Comment: Marked this as complete because I can see this is the right answer. I am however having problems with it working in my app. Would you be happy to continue a discussion with me to try and solve the issue i'm having?

Comment: Sure thing. How do you want to do it -is it something you can add to the question?

Comment: When there's enough comments SO lets you start a discussion separately. However as it happens I may have it sorted. I was subscribing to the result of the http get, not the Subject array. Now I'm subbed to the Subject array, everything is updating as expected :) Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing the whole observable, you probably want to just store the article array, like

```
articles: Article[]

fetch() {
    this.get(url).map(...).subscribe(articles => this.articles)
}
```

Then you can manipulate the `articles` list using standard array manipulation methods.

If you store the observable, it will re-run the http call every time you subscribe to it (or render it using `| async`) which is definitely not what you want.

But for the sake of completeness: if you do have an Observable of an array you want to add items to, you could use the map operator on it to add a specified item to it, e.g.

`observable.map(previousArray => previousArray.concat(itemtToBeAdded))`

Answer (score 0):

ex from angular 4 book ng-book

```
Subject<Array<String>> example =  new Subject<Array<String>>();


push(newvalue:String):void
{
  example.next((currentarray:String[]) : String[] => {
    return  currentarray.concat(newValue);
   })

}
```

what the following says in example.next is take the current array value Stored in the observable and concat a new value onto it and emit the new array value to subscribers. It is a lambda expression.I think this only works with subject observables because they hold unto the last value stored in their method subject.getValue();